# What is the etiquette for resubmitting math papers?

Tags: publications, mathematics

I have two math papers I have submitted for publication. Unfortunately neither paper was publishable in their original form. Both times I received a write up of the subject by the reviewer. I was particularly impressed by the write up on my second paper.

I have a couple of difficulties. I have now received quality feedback from another mathematician, but I can’t find references to the subject matter. I worry this information is from a class and not published material. Also I now have an unknown person who has provided feedback from an unknown source. How do I credit an unknown referee?

My last paper had what the editor considered a fatal error near the end of the paper. If I am resubmitting a paper to a different publication what is proper to mention about the earlier submission?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How do I credit an unknown referee?

Thank *anonymous referees* in the acknowledgements.

> If I am resubmitting a paper to a different publication what is proper to mention about the earlier submission?

You should follow the venue's rules, they may require you to mention, they may not.